# TimedRotatingFileHandler with format and console prints

Tags: python-2.7, logging

I like TimedRotatingFileHandler and I want to use it.

However my current logging is to my liking and includes some formatting, as well as logging in the console, like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    datefmt=dtfmt,
                    filename=logfile,
                    filemode='w')
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                              datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M')
console.setFormatter(formatter)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

logger = logging.getLogger('logger') 

logger.info('log something')
```

This returns something like this in a logfile:

> 2015-08-14 22:55:35 INFO    log something

And this in the console:

> 08-14 22:56 INFO     log something

How do I achieve this, but in addition have the log file rotating every midnight?

Answer (score 4):

An old question, but since it was the to search result on Google when i wanted to do the same thing I'll add my result.

In essence you should not use basicConfig. Add both handlers manually.

```
import logging, logging.handlers

#get the root logger
rootlogger = logging.getLogger()
#set overall level to debug, default is warning for root logger
rootlogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#setup logging to file, rotating at midnight
filelog = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler('./mylogfile.log',
                   when='midnight', interval=1)
filelog.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fileformatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
filelog.setFormatter(fileformatter)
rootlogger.addHandler(filelog)

#setup logging to console
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                          datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M')
console.setFormatter(formatter)
rootlogger.addHandler(console)

#get a logger for my script
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.info('This is logged to console and file')
logger.debug('This is only logged to file')
```

Comment: Thanks for bothering putting in an answer. I don't have time to verify your solution though. Cheers!